# DDD and Service Agents

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a WCF Service that I want to consume from my application. In following DDD I understanding that the semantics of connecting and consuming this service should be done through a Service Agent (Infrastructure Layer).

I am happy with this however it makes me ask the following questions;

1. Should the Service Agent Interface be defined in the Domain Layer?
2. Should a repository be defined that wraps this Service Agent?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service Agent usage should be inside infrastructure layer. SA interface doesn't belong to domain layer since it's not part of the business domain - it has strictly technical meaning (business experts probably didn't even heard of it).

Yes, repository is the most natural wrapper around WCF Service if it is dealing with fetching/storing data. If it is dealing with business operations domain service would be better choice.